# Interest Loop/while coding beginner

Tags: java, while-loop

I am a very beginner programmer taking a summer class. So please go easy with the code.
I need to create an Investment application that calculates how many years it will take for a $2,500 investment to be worth at least $5,000 if compounded annually at 7.5%. I do not know what a for loop is by the way.
I just cant figure out how to do this with LOOPS, not an equation but LOOPS. Please help !!

This is what i have so far.

```
public class Investment
{
    // Main method
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int MaxAm=5000; //the final worth of investment
    int Investment = 2500;
    double Interest = 0.075;
    double Time; 
    double TotalValue;

    //BLAH

    System.out.println("The amount of years it will take for a $2500 investment to be ");
    System.out.println("worth at least $5000 if compounded annually at 7.5% is: "+Time);

}
}
```

Comment: I would suggest spending a day or two messing around with for loops. They are much easier to understand than they look, and they are extremely helpful. This could be done purely with math afaik; no loops required.

Comment: @Carcigenicate `I just cant figure out how to do this with LOOPS, not an equation but LOOPS.` OP specifically wants loops.

Comment: @Jashaszun And I suggested looking into for loops since they also said that they don't understand them. My second point was in case they thought that a loop was required, but it's not actually a requirement. I read over the last sentence again, and you're right, it does say to use loops.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Oh yeah, sorry. I seem to have read right over your first two sentences too (or at least I forgot about them by the time I commented).

Comment: Np. @Robin Is this homework (it sounds like it)? I'd like to help you, but I really don't want to do your assignment for you.

Comment: This is more like one question out of 15 that i have to do by tomorrow and i have already finished 14.@Carcigenicate i just did it using a math formula. it works, its just that i dont know if im supposed to use loops or not (or how to use loops in this situation). the answer is 9.584 yearrs

Comment: Nvm, you said in the question that it is. I'll try to do an answer that doesn't do the assignment for you.

Comment: @RobinRobinson I have explained how a while loop works. And then solved your problem. I hope you do read through the explanation . :)

Comment: There's no point in using loops if you can solve it mathematically; the math will be faster. Unless they said explicitly to use loops, being able to do this in code mathematically is good. I would **still** learn for-loops though. As I mentioned earlier, they are extremely useful; I use them *at least* once in every project I've ever done.

Answer (score 2):

**For this, let us go through what a while loop is. Because this problem can be implemented using a while loop.**

```
while(condition){
    //things to do
}
```

This is the basic schema of a while loop. It checks the condition. If it is true, it executes all the instructions inside the brackets. After reaching the end it again comes back into the first parentheses and checks the condition again. If the condition checks out, it again executes the code inside the brackets. This continues for as long as the condition doesn't become false. If false, java ignores the instructions within the following brackets and moves on.

Now, in your case, you need to keep checking if the amount that is generated due to the interest each year is lesser than the `TotalValue`. If it is so, then you simulate it as one year. Or, in code, you add one to the count for the year. And then calculate the amount after adding interest and store it. If it becomes equal, or greater, then you need to stop the process of adding the years. As you have reached your answer. Its very simple really.

`amount<TotalValue` becomes false when amount reaches or exceeds `TotalValue`.

1. `while(amount<TotalValue) {`
2. `calculate amount after interest and store it.`
3. `year++`
4. `}`

As, we have already initialized Investment with the starting amount, we recycle it and store the value of amount in it itself. Don't get confused by the name.

```
public class Investment
{
    // Main method
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int MaxAm=5000; //the final worth of investment
    int Investment = 2500;
    double Interest = 0.075;
    double Time = 0; 
    double TotalValue = 5000;

    while(Investment<TotalValue) {

        Time++;
        Investment = Investment + (Investment*Interest);

    }   

    System.out.println("The amount of years it will take for a $2500 investment to be ");
    System.out.println("worth at least $5000 if compounded annually at 7.5% is: "+Time);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not thrilled that you did the assignment for them, but it's a good explanation. Note that this would be a perfect chance to show how to turn your example into a for-loop; it has a accumulator (`Time`), a condition, and code to run at the end of the loop (`Time++`). The only change would be  to start `Time` at 1 instead of 0. Also, I'd like to note that the OP's naming scheme goes against Java standards. Variables should start in a lower-case; upper-case is for class names.

Comment: Yes. lower case. That was going to be my next comment. And no, the time starts with 0, as if already the amount is the final amount, then it takes 0 years to reach there. :)

Comment: I'm saying if it was done as a for-loop with `time` as the accumulator/"loop-variable", `time` would have to start at 1 if it was incremented at the end of the loop instead of the beginning.

Comment: I just thought that this is something I can help him with. Lot of my friends lost interest in coding because they were too cool to read books yet had no one to guide them. So they ended up knowing very little, and when things got tough, they just gave up. I just thought that this is a very trivial concept and one that can be taught with this example. :)

Comment: You are counting the number of compounds/iterations, so time would start at 0. And you can't do it as a for loop with time as the accumulator, because you wouldn't have a way to relate that to the $5000.

Comment: We all wrote so much for him, where has he vanished now I wonder. :D :D

Answer (score 1):

To learn how to program, you need to break everything down into simple logic.
Goal: find number of YEARS it will take for a $2500 investment to be >= 5k
Facts you know:

- 1) Initial investment is 2500
- 2) Interest is compounded annually (a.k.a.: YEARly) at a rate of .075
- 3) You must continue to calculate interest WHILE the principal amount is < 5000
- 4) You must track the number of YEARs it takes to get to point 3
- Point 1 is the starting value you want your loop to be altering/updating - you need to keep a running value of your investment as you compound interest.
- Points 2 and 4 are connected because they both take place yearly; basically, whenever you compound your interest, you should be incrementing your time tracker.
- Point 3 is what you want to use as your loop condition, because you want to stop calculating interest after you've reached that condition.

That should be what you need to do the assignment. Also, get in the habit of initializing your variables (setting an initial value), ALWAYS start your variable names with a lowercase letter (underscores are acceptable for private variables), and avoid using words like Time (which, when capitalized, is actually the name of a java class). As a starter rule of thumb, only capitalize your Class Names (there are some other things you should capitalize, but not anything you will learn for a while). 
Here is a guideline, I changed your variable names and some of the types:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    final double interestRate = 0.075; // constant rate of interest
    double maxAmount = 5000; // 
    double initialInvestment = 2500;
    double finalInvestment = initialInvestment;
    int numberOfYears = 0; 

    while( /* insert condition */ ){

        // STEP: compound interest

        // STEP: increment year count
    }

    System.out.println("It will take " + numberOfYears 
                    + " for your investment of " + initialInvestment 
                    + " to be worth at least " + maxAmount 
                    + " if compounded annually at a rate of " + interestRate);

}
```